# Absolute Value System of Equation Word Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

This set up is bizarre. In the first paragraph, it talks about a distance of 6 feet and a slope of 3, but then in the next paragraph, the distance is 30 feet and there are two coordinates from which to derive a slope. Combining this with the additional complexity of the absolute value is too much. I don't know where to start. Thank you in advance. [AbValHeadlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve49A.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the point that's confusing you is the 6ft vs 30ft distances: The problem is saying that they are traveling in parallel lanes that are 6ft apart, and asking for the intersection of their headlights at the point when they are 30 feet from passing eachother.

This is confirmed by the points given for the cars: one is at (6, 0) and one is at (0, 30). They are travelling in the positive and negative y directions respectively.